# How do I convert a Keynote presentation recording video into a YouTube-able format?

Tags: mac, video, youtube, iwork, iwork-keynote

I've created a presentation using Keynote '08 from Apple's iWork. I recorded an audio voiceover and exported a .mov file. However, since I recorded the audio in multiple takes, Keynote exports the file with *multiple* (AAC) audio streams. YouTube doesn't accept videos with multiple audio streams. It simply uses the first audio stream so that after a few minutes, the audio drops out.

How do I convert this video into a format that can be uploaded to YouTube?

Comment: Can you open the video in QuickTime (Pro) or iMovie and Export it?

Answer (score 0):

After exporting to iDVD, I was able to grab the intermediate file, which contains a single video and single audio stream (and an extraneous data stream) and directly upload this to YouTube without issue.

Some failed attempts (for others that might be thinking down this route): Using ffmpeg, sox, faad, and the like on a Linux box to flatten the audio stream and then reconstituting a final .mov file. -- ffmpeg was not able to correctly copy over the video stream.

White Phoenix: These rather expensive programs (QuickTime Pro / iMovie) would probably do the job. But I'm a cheapskate. :-)